# Suggest a tutorial for Backbone.js and php as backend

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js

Hi I'm making an app that uses backbone.js as front end. It sends restful calls to server. I have made the front end. I want to create a backend on php where I can receive these requests, fetch the data from the database and give the response.

Can you suggest tutorials for the same or show the approach to make the backend server in php?

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: try using chat to tackle this request => http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, this one worked for me, PHP API + Backbone

http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/

Comment: I'll host my server side code on a remote server. Now Where exactly in my Backbone code should I mention about this remote server URL ?

Comment: on the Backbone docs, read about "sync", "url" & "urlRoot"

Comment: The link is not working !